# Reading & using cookie values with javascript

Tags: javascript, cookies

Just off the get go I am incredibly new to javascript, apologies for any silly comments or obvious mistakes in advance.

This is what I'm currently working with:

```
<div id="currency_select">
    <form action="/Default.asp?" method="post" name="CurrencyChoice">
        <select onchange="this.form.submit()" name="ER_ID">
            <option value="3">EUR</option>
            <option value="2">GBP</option>
        </select>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            document.forms['CurrencyChoice'].elements['ER_ID'].value = '';
        </script>
    </form>
</div>
```

I want the value from the following cookie "ER%5fID" to be read and then inserted in the `value=''`field above.

To be completely honest I'm at abit of a loss as I'm not sure what the best way is to read the cookie's value and then have its value inserted where I want.

Once again apologies for any newbie mistakes. I'm having to learn javascript on the fly and I had to start a few days ago.

So I have spent a fair amount of time today trying to figure out what I need which I think is this:

```
function getCookie(c_name)
{
    var i,x,y,ARRcookies=document.cookie.split(";");

    for (i=0;i<ARRcookies.length;i++)
    {
        x=ARRcookies[i].substr(0,ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
        y=ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=")+1);
        x=x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
        if (x==c_name)
        {
            return unescape(y);
        }
     }
}
```

However I'm still unsure as to how to have the appropriate result return within the value field?

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: or if you don't care about old IE, just ER_ID.value='' ...

Comment: google "setCookie" and then if needed, "getCookie"

Comment: you might want to consider using localStorage for this if you care about site performance...

Comment: ER_ID.value=getCookie('ER%5fID');  though i'm not sure the cookie can have a url-escaped name like that...

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry I just do not care to rewrite this, the [W3Scools tutorial on cookies](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp) is quite comprihensive and even gives you fully completed functions for reading and writing cookies.

It's also a good resource for general JS learning so you should definitely check it out.

The code there is as follows:

```
function setCookie(cname,cvalue,exdays)
{
var d = new Date();
d.setTime(d.getTime()+(exdays*24*60*60*1000));
var expires = "expires="+d.toGMTString();
document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
} 

function getCookie(cname)
{
var name = cname + "=";
var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++)
  {
  var c = ca[i].trim();
  if (c.indexOf(name)==0) return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
  }
return "";
}
```

And usage is:

```
function checkCookie()
{
var username=getCookie("username");
if (username!="")
  {
  alert("Welcome again " + username);
  }
else
  {
  username = prompt("Please enter your name:","");
  if (username!="" && username!=null)
    {
    setCookie("username",username,365);
    }
  }
}
```

But you can read more in W3Scools own website.

**EDIT :** So here is the promised fully functional sample in your specific case:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
        <title>Cookie Example</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">

        //adds the [String].trim() method to the [String] object if missing
        if(!String.prototype.trim) {
          String.prototype.trim = function () {
            return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,'');
          };
        }

            var cookieName = "ER_ID";

            function setCookie(cname,cvalue,exdays)
            {
                var d = new Date();
                d.setTime(d.getTime()+(exdays*24*60*60*1000));
                var expires = "expires="+d.toGMTString();
                document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
            } 

            function getCookie(cname)
            {
                var name = cname + "=";
                var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
                for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++){
                    var c = ca[i].trim();
                    if (c.indexOf(name)==0) return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
                }
                return "";
            }

            function setOptionFromCookie() {

                var select = document.getElementById('ER_ID'), index, value = getCookie(cookieName);

                index = select.options.length;
                while(index--) {
                    if(select.options[index].value == value) {
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if(index > -1) {
                    select.selectedIndex = index;
                } else {
                    alert('no such value in selection');
                }
            }

            function setValue() {
                var value = document.getElementById('value').value;
                setCookie(cookieName, value, 365);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        The value that will go into the cookie "ER_ID": <input id="value" value="2" />
        <br/>
        <button onclick="setValue()">Set Cookie</button>
        <button onclick="setOptionFromCookie()">Set Option from cookie</button>
        <hr />
        <div id="currency_select">
            <form action="/Default.asp?" method="post" name="CurrencyChoice">
                <select onchange="this.form.submit()" id="ER_ID" name="ER_ID">
                    <option value="1" selected="selected">Select Currency</option>
                    <option value="3">EUR</option>
                    <option value="2">GBP</option>
                </select>
                <script type="text/javascript">

                </script>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Because I do not have such a cookie in my browser I also made a possibility for you to set the cookie. But it should be fairly easy to understand. Simply set the cookie first and then press "Set Option from cookie" to read the cookie and set the option based on the value.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I didn't ask you to write anything for me, Also I've spent the last three days on W3School for various JS related basics including this one. But thanks for pointing out the obvious though. 
Apologies if my lack of knowledge is an annoyance...

Comment: @Zen You misunderstand, for reading & writing cookies the answer I would give is the same one as in W3Scools (no point in rewriting something that exists, I use the same ones myself), but if you still do not get how to use them then I'll rewamp my answer for you, for your specific case.

Comment: @ZenAz as promiced here is a fully functioning sample using your HTML (mostly) using the same functions as in W3Schools, btw next time you ask something note what you aleady know!

Comment: Once again I do apologise for my lack of knowledge on the matter. I should have stated that to start with. I cant believe it was as simple as a "value id" that I was missing...Whilst I really didn't want to inconvenience you or anyone with writing this its very much appreciated.

I feel even stupider then I did before.

thanks again